# Add column to new document library template

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, office-365, lookup-column, online

a was trying to found a  way to add a new column to List / Document L template!? 
I want to add a lookuop column to this view, is it possible ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I dont think there is an OOTB method to implement your requirement. So in our project we have created an Custom sharepoint application page which will be placed in 15 hives folder. We have created a custom action in the Ribbon which will call this application page when clicked.

In that application page we have fields to enter the Title, Description, Security permissions and Content type selection fields. Once the user enters the details and clicks save a document library will be created based on the user specified values. The custom application page has code behind to implement the functionality.

So try creating a sharepoint custom application page.